# No layout and menu not working

Tags: 8

I installed latest version of Drupal 8.1.3 on my site.
Everything went fine and no error message.
But after installation done, my homepage became this.
No layout, menu not working.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was disabled cgi execution and make the CSS unable to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the sites/default/files directory and any directory inside that are writeable from the account used to run Apache. After that, force Drupal to clear its cache.
It happened to me too, and all the times it was because Drupal was not able to write the files it uses for rendering the page in that directory.

Comment: How do I clear the cache? I am not able to enter the configuration page. I have just change sites/default/files directory permission to 777,

Comment: Do you have Drush installed?

Comment: Yes. How to clear cache?

Comment: With drush, you cd into your drupal directory, and then the command is `drush cr`.  cr stands for "cache-rebuild", which is what you want.